# Does forEach() bind by reference?

Tags: javascript, foreach, pass-by-reference

```
var arr = ['Foo'];

arr.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item);
  item = 'Lorem';
  console.dir(arr[0]);

});

for (var item in arr){
  arr[item] = 'Ipsum';
  console.dir(arr[0]);
}
```

Like the code above shows, I noticed that changing the value of an item passed to the callback of `forEach()` does not cause the iterated object to alter.

Using `for...in` certainly does.

**Why is that & how should I alter values in an array?**

I find that the topic is covered quite confusing on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: The order in which properties are visited in [*for..in*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) is entirely implementation dependent. [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) visits only numeric properties from 0 to *length* and strictly in numeric order, it has nothing to do with the value. The link to MDN is broken, perhaps you meant [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Would you ***please*** put your code here instead of on some other site?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Using for...in certainly does.

No it doesn't. Your `forEach` loop is equivalent to this `for...in` loop (apart from the order):

```
for (var index in arr) {
  var item = arr[index];
  console.log(item);
  item = 'Lorem';
  console.dir(arr[0]);
}
```

Do you see that the array isn't modified either? That's because JavaScript is always [*pass-by-value*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_by_value#Call_by_value), and there is a very simple rule to keep in mind:

> Assigning a value to a variable **never** changes the value of another variable or data structure.

That means, assigning a new value to `item`, cannot change an element of `arr`. If you want to to modify the array, you have to mutate it directly by assigning a value to an index, i.e.

```
arr[index] = 'foo';
```

Comment: I find that this sounds confusing as objects **are** passed by reference

Comment: @Sprottenwels: No. This is correct. JavaScript only has pass-by-value. The only values in JavaScript are primitives and pointers to objects. "Objects" are not values and cannot be "passed".

Comment: @Sprottenwels: It is confusing, but *pass-by-reference* has a different and very specific meaning. You can read about in the Wikipedia article. Also have a look at the section *pass-by-sharing*, which is closer to how JS works, but it's not a very common term.

Answer (score 17):

In your case, the `item` variable is passed by value, because it is of a primitive value. If it were a json object, and you would change one of its properties, it would be reflected on the original list.

In this situation, you can use other arguments that the `forEach` has. For example:

```
arr.forEach(element, index, array) {
    ...
}
```

Using these arguments, you can affect directly `array[index]`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Notice that callback in `forEach` gets three arguments. The second one being an index of current element, and the third one the array itself. If you want to modify the array, use these two arguments.