# Why dosen't it change when using spread funtion?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread

In this case, a is changed.

```
var a = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a : 5, b : 6}];
a.forEach(x => x.a = 7);

0: {a: 7, b: 2}
1: {a: 7, b: 4}
2: {a: 7, b: 6}
```

But in this case a is not changed.

```
var a = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a : 5, b : 6}];
a.forEach(x => x = {...x, a:7});

0: {a: 1, b: 2}
1: {a: 3, b: 4}
2: {a: 5, b: 6}
```

what is difference?

Comment: Spread syntax shallow-clones the object, so the original object (in the array) remains unchanged

Comment: `forEach` calls your function with each element of the array as an argument. Assigning a new object to the parameter `x` won’t change anything else (e.g. the array). `x.a = 7` is different because it’s changing the object itself, rather than changing a variable, and the array holds that same object.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762112/why-is-my-foreach-loop-not-editing-my-array

Comment: a.forEach((value, i)=> {  a[i].a = 7;  }); you can try like this. This basically edits your a variable.