# Take word from list, run function, and move on to next word

Tags: javascript

I have a text file (separated by `', '` between each word) and a function that assigns a word a value (where `a = 1`, `z = 26`) when it is run. (ex: `sumChars('JavaScript')` returns `119`.) My question is, how do I get only the first word, run the function with that, and move on to the next word? I know that after using `fetch(url)` to get the file, I can use `.then(d => d.replace(/\n/, '')).then(d => d.replace("', '", ''))` to get rid of everything else.

Comment: try to split your string into an array then call your function to each element: `const resp = d.split(', ').map(x => sumChars(x))`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with strings in Javascript is to use **regular expression**, with g (global) flag to process all ocurrences in the string.

```
var list = [], sums = [];

fetch(url) 
 .then(txt => list = txt.replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '').split(","); return list;)
 .then(res => res.forEach((wrd,idx,arr) => { sums[idx]=0; 
 wrd.split('').forEach(char => sums[idx] += char.charCodeAt(0)-96)}) 
    );

console.log("result: ", list,sums);
```

As a reference to get characters value [convert characters to ascii code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript).
As a reference to bind array elements in foreach loop [foreach loop by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964111/does-foreach-bind-by-reference).